# Angular apply number pipe in component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I've a piece of snippet

```
this.subscription = this.crCount$.subscribe((count:number) => {
       if (count) {
        this.tabs.push({
           id: 'tab3',
           title: `Associate / Linked Change Request (${count} | number:'2.0')`,
           active: false,
        });
     }
```

I'm trying to apply angular's inbuild `number` pipe in component's typescript file.
But it seems like the expression is not evaluating, it displays raw non evaluated expression
in UI. How can i resolve this?

Comment: @NilsKähler Ok we need to import DecimalPipe and apply transform method. I'll give it a try

Comment: Answer - this.decimalPipe.transform( count, '2.0' ). Thanks